# how to pass command line vairable to nps?

Tags: node-modules, package.json, pnpm, nps

How can I pass parameter from command line to nps script that is called other nps script? I know I can pass parameter to nps script by `nps "script arg"` but I would like to execute command line like `./pnpm start test.unit file_path` to actually execute `./node_modules/xxx/bin/xxx run --spec file_path`

So far, if I set up package.json as following I can get what I want by `./pnpm run test file_path` == `xxx run --spec file_path`

```
#package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nps",
    "test": "xxx run --spec"
  },
./pnpm run test file_path
```

Now I would like to set up `nps` but how can I make nps read parameter from command line? so when I call `./pnpm start test file_path` it can execute `xxx run --spec file`

```
#package-scripts.yaml
test:
    default: nps test.unit #?
    unit: xxx run --spec '@?' #?
```

the closed PR i can find is https://github.com/sezna/nps/issues/133#issuecomment-301915698 but i still do not understand how to pass it

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: no, it end up i have to use `"` like nps test unit "<file>"